# Managing Remote Desktop to 50+ remote locations all with their own VPN

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, remote-access, rdp

We are a small business that serves a piece of software to over 50 other busineses in the US. Each business has its own VPN that is not allowed access to the internet. To look at our software that is running on these PCs, we have to log in to that business' VPN and then open pcAnywhere to view the screen.

How can I better manage these computers? Each VPN has its own set of login information and each pcAnywhere host has its own set of login information. As we grow I can see this becoming a nightmare to manage. (It's already quite time consuming switching between remote computers.)

Comment: The real problem is using pcAnywhere. Is it possible to manage the application without using some kind of interactive GUI?

Comment: Nope! The whole point is to use the GUI software located on the remote job PC.

Comment: I found a solution with http://www.remotedesktopmanager.com but its pretty clunky/buggy...

Answer (score 0):

One option: Have your dev team write or use a (secure) management protocol for the software itself that doesn't depend on having console access to the machine on which it runs.